# Executing PHP Code in Contact Form 7 Textarea

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got a contact form 7 form that I'm looking to execute php in the textarea field.

When I tested this with a normal form (ie not a plugin) it worked fine;

```
 <textarea name="customer-issue" rows="10" cols="40"><?php if(isset($_GET['content'])) { echo $_GET['content']; } ?></textarea>
```

Does anyone know how you would go about being able to do this in CF7

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the code of JpDevs:

He forgot some ' ' at setting the $html variable. This is working:

```
function cs7() {
    $var=$_GET['content'];
    $html='<p>'.$var.'</p>';
    return $html;
}

add_shortcode('cs7', 'cs7');
```

Then just add [cs7] to your form.

When you use ' ', you have to write the variables **outside** by connecting with points:

```
$result = '<p>'.$var.'</p>';
```

When you use " ", you can write them **inside**:

```
$result = "<p>$var</p>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly have a look at below mentioned link  :

`https://wordpress.org/support/topic/contact-form-7-input-fields-values-as-php-get-viarables`

Hope this helps for you

Comment: Thanks - Had a look at this previously, it's for an older version of Contact Form 7 so no longer works

Comment: @Adam, for the code mentioned by Jishad, use it like this : $html='<p>'.$var.'</p>'; instead of $html='<p>.$var.</p>';

Answer (score 0):

Make the code

```
$var=$_GET['content'];
```

to short code,

and the paste the generated shortcode in your contact form 7 text area

Eg:

functions.php

```
function cs7() 
{
$var=$_GET['content'];
$html='<p>.$var.</p>';
return $html;
}
add_shortcode('cs7', 'cs7');
```

add [cs7] in contact form area

Comment: Hi Jishad, I've tried this http://crm.godesignweb.co.uk/contact/ and it still doesn't work.

Comment: It just echos the plain text <p>.$var.</p>