# Use URL parameter in Contact Form 7 Field

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I would like to add some PHP in my form created with Contact Form 7, a WordPress plugin.
I've already tried this but it didn't work: [Executing PHP Code in Contact Form 7 Textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27817294/executing-php-code-in-contact-form-7-textarea).
Every time I insert the function, my website crashes.

I have a variable stored in a $_SESSION. I have put that variable in a hidden input and now I would like to take the value of the hidden input and place it in the contact form.
How can I do this? Thanks!

[Screenshot of the website and the hidden input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kFia.png)

[Screenshot of the back-end of the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hOx8.png)

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for the [wpcf7_form_hidden_fields](http://hookr.io/filters/wpcf7_form_hidden_fields/) filter.

Comment: What are you trying to add with php? Probably there are better ways than adding custom php in the middle of a form

Comment: @DannyBattison And how do I use that?

Comment: @BenB I'm trying to paste the URL from the previous page into the form. This way we know where the request is coming from. It's for a website of a car dealer. So people click on a car -> Click on 'More information' -> Go to the next page and fill out the form. I would like to paste the URL of the previous page into that form. Now I already have the URL stored in a $_SESSION var but now I need to paste that in a form. And I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Make your own form tag.https://contactform7.com/2015/01/10/adding-a-custom-form-tag/

Comment: @HowardE That's the thing. If I use code like that on the page, the website crashes. Check: https://imgur.com/zZv0qjf. It's Dutch but it says: A critical error has occurred on your website. And I also can't edit the functions.php.

Comment: Yes.  Create your own custom form tag, where you use something like [session-var] and make that read the session variable and push it to a hidden form field.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think this approach can work for you.

1. Set a url param to the link. Example `domain.com/more-info?previous-link=home-page`
2. In your form add this field

   ```
   [text* previous-link default:get default:post_meta "Previous link"]
   ```

You can see more examples in the [docs](https://contactform7.com/getting-default-values-from-the-context/)

Comment: This worked! Although I bumped into another problem which was passing through multiple parameters in a URL. But using this topic I solved it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102489/passing-multiple-variables-to-another-page-in-url. Thank you very much and also all the other people who helped :)